# JSON logic Checking best approach

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a search form and more than 15 fields for searching. I have to call different API's based on the search Parameters

For instance below is my request Params

```
    requestParams = {
    firstName : 'Jack',
    lastName : 'Jill',
    dob : '12-10-2020',
    email : '',
    phone : '',
    address: '',
    postCode: '',
    customerID : '11111111',
    status : 'Active'
}
```

Currently am using if conditions to achieve this

```js
if( checkNull(requestParams.firstName) && checkNull(requestParams.lastName) ) {
        callApiOne();
}

if( checkNull(requestParams.customerID)) {
        callApiTwo();
}

if( checkNull(requestParams.firstName) && checkNull(requestParams.status) ) {
        callApiOne();
}

if( checkNull(requestParams.firstName) && checkNull(requestParams.phone) ) {
        callApiTwo();
}
```

My search combination list may increase up to 25 what is the best approach to keep it configurable and reusable.

Comment: Why are you calling the `checkNull` function additionally?

Comment: How many api calls do you have?

Comment: checkNull is a utility function for checking  empty values

Comment: I have only two API calls

Comment: You don't need to explicitly check for `null` values the if loop will automatically do that.

Comment: And when do you call `apiOne` and when do you call `apiTwo`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the input you have given. I came up with the solution.

Given your request param

```
const requestParams = {
    firstName : 'Jack',
    lastName : 'Jill',
    dob : '12-10-2020',
    email : '',
    phone : '',
    address: '',
    postCode: '',
    customerID : '11111111',
    status : 'Active',
};
```

First create a variable containing all the fields you need which contains the key of your request param and the api based on that.

```
const PARAMS = [
    { key: 'lastName', api: 'apiOne' },
    { key: 'dob', api: 'apiTwo' },
    { key: 'email', api: 'apiThree' },
    { key: 'phone', api: 'apiFour' },
    { key: 'address', api: 'apiFive' },
    { key: 'postCode', api: 'apiSix' },
    { key: 'customerID', api: 'apiSeven' },
    { key: 'status', api: 'apiOne' },
];
```

Then loop through each items from above list and check if `requestParams` contains a value and if its not null. For some like `customerID` you can have a exception.

```
PARAMS.forEach(({ key, api }) => {
    if (key === 'customerID' && checkNull(requestParams.customerID)) {
        callApi(api);
        return;
    }

    if (checkNull(requestParams.firstName) && checkNull(requestParams[key])) {
        callApi(api);
    }
});
```

If you post your full code I can help you better.

Comment: `apiOne` is called at multiple situations, see OPs question. Calls are dependent on multiple keys.

Comment: This does work even if apiOne is called multiple times. All you need to do is have same api in the api field. Just like I have in the updated code.